# Change Perl Memoize Cache during runtime

Tags: perl, memoization

I have a method that reads a flag from a file and it is memoized.

```
use Memoize;

my %cache;
memoize('readFlag',  SCALAR_CACHE => [HASH => \%cache]);
sub readFlag {
 # read flag & return
}
```

Memoize works fine and I get the cached value always. Now, I want to modify this cache entry during runtime and any running script to pick up the change. Tried using a pointer to the method, however that just creates another entry in the hashmap and sets the value but does not update the existing value.

```
$cache{\readFlag} = newVal;
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is `memoize()`?

Comment: @Shawn See update

Comment: [flush_cache](https://metacpan.org/pod/Memoize#flush_cache) should work.  You'd need a way of triggering it from outside your running script with a signal or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache would be keyed on parameters (not whatever you think `\readFlag` does).

Specifically,

> The default normalizer just concatenates the arguments with character 28 in between

So if you wanted to make it so `readFlag("a", "b")` returns `c`, you would use

```perl
$cache{ join chr(28), "a", "b" } = "c";
```

Note that this won't affect "any running script", just this process. The cache only exists in the process. You can take steps to make the cache persistent, but you didn't show anything of the kind.

Comment: If there is more than one subroutine without parameters in the same package, how will the cache work?

Comment: Each sub has its own cache. Normally. You could use `HASH => \%cache`  to pass the same hash to both, but that would be stupid.